# Inherited view controller will not dismiss itself in a block #ICETutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I'm using [ICETutorial](http://icepat.github.io/ICETutorial/) with cocoapods.

I'm using it in a SettingsViewController where you can view the tutorial in settings.

```
// SettingsViewController.m
Tutorial2ViewController *vc = [[Tutorial2ViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

And `Tutorial2ViewController` inherits from `ICETutorialController`

```
@interface Tutorial2ViewController : ICETutorialController
```

ICETutorialPages have buttons that will trigger a callback. It takes in a block. So in my implementation, I have this:

```
- (id)init
{
    ICETutorialPage *layer1 = [[ICETutorialPage alloc] initWithSubTitle:@"Page 1" description:@"Page 1" pictureName:@"Tutorial1_640x1136.png"];
    NSArray *tutorialLayers = @[layer1];

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ICETutorialController_iPhone" bundle:nil andPages:tutorialLayers];

    __weak Tutorial2ViewController *vc = self;
    [self setButton1Block:^(UIButton *button){
        NSLog(@"Button 1 pressed.");
        [[vc.navigationController topViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }];

    if (self != nil)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```

The reason why I put all the code in init is that I don't want `SettingsViewController` to know anything about how the `Tutorial2ViewController` works. Settings should alloc and init, push to the navigation controller stack and the `Tutorial2ViewController` should know how to handle itself.

I do get the NSLog that button1 is pressed but the view controller does not dismiss itself and return me to the SettingsViewController.

I will contact the creator of the library and ask him/her to see this question also. I feel that this is me not misunderstanding blocks, navigation controllers, cocoapods, etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];